# Vite (in Laravel) cannot use with static assets from public directory

Tags: laravel, webpack, vite

I have a problem when I update to laravel 9.19 (using vite instead of webpack).
In my project I using some static assets from public directory like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/assets/slick.css">` or  `<script src="/js/assets/slick.min.js"></script>` and have 2 files to compile from resources like `resources/sass/app.scss` and 'resources/js/app.js', the same for `.js` files. On webpack I do something like this:

> `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('/css/app.css') }}"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/assets/slick.css">` ... and
> `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('/css/style.css') }}`
> the same situation for `.js` files and all works perfectlly. How I can do this with **Vite**

Answer (score 2):

You can read the [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite#loading-your-scripts-and-styles), you should use the blade directive `@vite()` an use the project path:

```html
@vite('resources/sass/app.scss')


@vite('resources/js/app.js')
```

Comment: I'm try to use that but the assets didn't see the the dependencies where I use in app.js

Comment: @EugenIspas have you found the solution for your problem?